# Custom input component with React Hook Form 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this component:

```
const TextInput = ({ type = 'text', fullWidth = false, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type={type}
      className={`text-input ${classNames([fullWidth, 'fullwidth'])}`}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
```

and then I have this code:

```
const { register } = useForm();

//then in the return
<TextInput type='email' fullWidth {...register('email')} />
```

And I'm getting this error:

Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

How can I solved this? From what I looked I have to pass refs to the input but I don't know how to do this..

Answer (score 2):

```
const TextInput = ({ register ,name,type = 'text', fullWidth = false, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type={type}
      {...register(name)}
      className={`text-input ${classNames([fullWidth, 'fullwidth'])}`}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
```

**And then you can do**

```
const { register } = useForm();

//then in the return
<TextInput type='email' fullWidth register={register} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so what I needed to do is use forwardRef like this:

```
const TextInput = React.forwardRef(({ type = 'text', fullWidth = false, ...rest }, ref) => {
  return (
    <input
      type={type}
      className={`text-input ${classNames([fullWidth, 'fullwidth'])}`}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
});
```